# Input array for fitting method

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

This code returns the expected results. But there are 2 pandas methods involved. Can I use only 1 method or remove pandas from fit_transform?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = [-1, 2,1, 18]
scaler.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(data)))

array([[0.        ],
       [0.15789474],
       [0.10526316],
       [1.        ]])
```

---

Update: I tried feeding the list, but got an error:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = [-1, 2,1, 18]
scaler.fit_transform(data)

# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead
```

This works, but getting wrong results:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = [-1, 2,1, 18]
scaler.fit_transform([data])

# array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Perhaps reading the docs would have helped? It does say the function is meant to take lists, arrays, or similar. Not sure where you got the idea to introduce pandas objects here.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly apply `fit_transform` like this without `pandas`

```
data = np.array(data).reshape(-1,1).astype(np.float32)
scaler.fit_transform(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

You can directly create a dataframe from the list and feed it to the scaler, which would require any reshaping.

```
scaler.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Option 2:

If you want to do with numpy,

```
scaler.fit_transform(np.array(data)[:,np.newaxis])
```

or you can go with the suggestion given by @Oswald